# Trying to remove the 5th name entered from my array. I'm getting a cannot find symbol error and I can't figure out why

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment6APt2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");
    String [] names = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();

    }
    names.remove(4); 
    arrayMethod(names);
}

 private static void arrayMethod(String[] names) 

{

 for (String a : names)

{

System.out.printf( "%s",a);

    } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Who told you you can call `remove()` on an array?

Comment: Which symbol is undefined?

Comment: Also, it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "removing" an item from a fixed-length array? What were you expecting to happen here?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `remove` method for arrays, and this operation really doesn't make sense anyway. What does it even mean to "remove" an item from a fixed-size array?

The closest thing you can do is set array index 5 to `null`, which is just a simple assignment. I'm not sure I recommend doing that, though. You probably want to either rethink doing that or just use a variable-size data structure.